# Encountered problems when compiling android 12

Tags: android, makefile

I encountered the following problem when using Ubuntu 20 to compile the Android 12 source code. Although my code is customized by the company, it is still based on AOSP. I think this should be a general problem because I found others in https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/Error-when-compiling-for-Android-11/td-p/1504769 also encountered this problem, but no solution.

```
Internal error. Please report to android-llvm@google.com.
compiler_wrapper.go:178: failed to execute &main.command{Path:"prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r416183b1/bin/clang++.real", Args:[]string{"-c", "-Wa,--noexecstack", "-fPIC", "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE", "-D_
FORTIFY_SOURCE=2", "-fstack-protector", "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS", "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS", "--gcc-toolchain=prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8", "--sysroot", "prebuilts/gcc/linux-x
86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/sysroot", "-fstack-protector-strong", "-m64", "-DANDROID", "-fmessage-length=0", "-W", "-Wall", "-Wno-unused", "-Winit-self", "-Wpointer-arith", "-Wunreachable-code-loop
-increment", "-no-canonical-prefixes", "-DNDEBUG", "-UDEBUG", "-fno-exceptions", "-Wno-multichar", "-O2", "-g", "-fdebug-info-for-profiling", "-fno-strict-aliasing", "-Werror=date-time", "-Werror=pragma-p
ack", "-Werror=pragma-pack-suspicious-include", "-Werror=string-plus-int", "-Werror=unreachable-code-loop-increment", "-fdebug-prefix-map=/proc/self/cwd=", "-D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof", "-fa
ddrsig", "-fcommon", "-Werror=int-conversion", "-fexperimental-new-pass-manager", "-Wno-reserved-id-macro", "-Wno-unused-command-line-argument", "-fcolor-diagnostics", "-Wno-sign-compare", "-Wno-defaulted
-function-deleted", "-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override", "-Wno-c99-designator", "-Wno-gnu-folding-constant", "-Wunguarded-availability", "-D__ANDROID_UNAVAILABLE_SYMBOLS_ARE_WEAK__", "-ftrivial-auto-var-
init=zero", "-enable-trivial-auto-var-init-zero-knowing-it-will-be-removed-from-clang", "-Wno-enum-compare", "-Wno-enum-compare-switch", "-Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic", "-Wno-null-dereference", "-Wno-poin
ter-compare", "-Wno-xor-used-as-pow", "-Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class", "-Wno-psabi", "-target", "x86_64-linux-gnu", "-Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/x86_64-linux/bin", "-DANDRO
ID_STRICT", "-fPIE", "-Wsign-promo", "-Wimplicit-fallthrough", "-D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_THREAD_SAFETY_ANNOTATIONS", "-Wno-gnu-include-next", "-Isystem/tools/hidl", "-Isystem/libbase/include", "-Iexternal/fmtlib/
include", "-Iexternal/boringssl/src/include", "-Isystem/tools/hidl", "-Isystem/tools/hidl/hashing/include", "-Isystem/tools/hidl/host_utils/include", "-Isystem/tools/hidl/utils/include", "-Iexternal/jsonc
pp/include", "-Isystem/logging/liblog/include", "-Iexternal/libcxx/include", "-Iexternal/libcxxabi/include", "-Wall", "-Werror", "-O0", "-g", "-std=gnu++17", "-nostdinc++", "-Isystem/core/include", "-Isys
tem/logging/liblog/include", "-Isystem/media/audio/include", "-Ihardware/libhardware/include", "-Ihardware/libhardware_legacy/include", "-Ihardware/ril/include", "-Iframeworks/native/include", "-Iframewor
ks/native/opengl/include", "-Iframeworks/av/include", "-Werror=bool-operation", "-Werror=implicit-int-float-conversion", "-Werror=int-in-bool-context", "-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast", "-Werror=pointer-to-i
nt-cast", "-Werror=string-compare", "-Werror=xor-used-as-pow", "-Wno-void-pointer-to-enum-cast", "-Wno-void-pointer-to-int-cast", "-Wno-pointer-to-int-cast", "-Werror=address-of-temporary", "-Werror=retur
n-type", "-Wno-tautological-constant-compare", "-Wno-tautological-type-limit-compare", "-Wno-reorder-init-list", "-Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion", "-Wno-int-in-bool-context", "-Wno-sizeof-array-div", 
"-Wno-tautological-overlap-compare", "-Wno-deprecated-copy", "-Wno-range-loop-construct", "-Wno-misleading-indentation", "-Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-constant", "-Wno-deprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion", 
"-Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion", "-Wno-string-compare", "-Wno-enum-enum-conversion", "-Wno-enum-float-conversion", "-Wno-pessimizing-move", "-Wno-non-c-typedef-for-linkage", "-Wno-string-concatenat
ion", "-MD", "-MF", "out/soong/.intermediates/system/tools/hidl/hidl-gen/linux_glibc_x86_64/obj/system/tools/hidl/main.o.d", "-o", "out/soong/.intermediates/system/tools/hidl/hidl-gen/linux_glibc_x86_64/o
bj/system/tools/hidl/main.o", "system/tools/hidl/main.cpp"}, EnvUpdates:[]string(nil)}: go_exec.go:22: exec error: exec format error
10:00:52 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I tried increasing the swap space and restarting the computer, but still encountered this problem.

Comment: I don't know why you've tagged this question with `makefile`.  You appear to be using ninja not make.

Comment: Hi @fielding zhou, could you please post how do you fix the problem at last on the thread? I have same problem